# after scale, the borderImage show unwanted transparent line

Tags: css, border-image

I use borderImage to show one image (without scale), it can show normally. But if I scale it `(transform:scale(1.2))`, the borderImage will have unwanted transparent line. is there any way to solve this problem?

chrome version is: Version 63.0.3239.132 (Official Build) (64-bit)

the test code as following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Demo</title>
  </head>

  <body>      
      <div style='position: absolute; left: 50px; top: 50px; width: 304px; height: 200px; 
                  border-style: solid; 
                  border-width: 0px 10px; 
                  border-image: url(http://d3grnps0i0ixod.cloudfront.net/platform/image/contents/vc/42/02/41/20180119020137369738_PR20171221ILU0ITYJDI_EyyKSBVMV20180119122202307.jpg) 0 10 0 10 fill stretch; 
                  transform: scale(1.2)'>
      </div>
 </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: To expand on Paulie's comment, please show your rendered html and css rather than the pre-rendered version (ie what is shown in your browser - press crtl u copy and paste)

Comment: please clarify your question

Comment: thanks for all your sugestion, I have improve my question